# Objective C: Recording looping

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, avfoundation

I want to know my error or if I forgot something in my code...

```
-(IBAction)playRecord
{
    NSLog(@"stop rec");
    [recorder stop];
    [self playSound];


}
-(void)playSound{
    NSLog(@"play");
    recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MySound.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];
    NSURL *urlRecord = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath isDirectory:NO];
    NSError *errorRecord;
    soundRecord = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlRecord error:&errorRecord];
    [soundRecord prepareToPlay];
    [soundRecord play];
    soundRecord.delegate = self;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(stopPlayRec) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    [recorder record];
    NSLog(@"Finish");
}

-(void)stopPlayRec
{
    if ([recorder peakPowerForChannel:(0)] <= (-30) && [recorder peakPowerForChannel:(0)] >= (-43))//detecting voice then record
    {
            NSLog(@"test");
            [self playRecord];

    }
    else 
        {
            if ([recorder peakPowerForChannel:(0)] >= (-160))
            {
                NSLog(@"playing");

            }
        }
}
```

in my `viewdidload` I initialize already my "Start Recording" function,

```
[self startRecording];
```

so that at the moment that my view load it is starting to record..then after I press play button it will playback my recorded file...the flow of my code is after I press play button it will now loop back to recording if it the PeakPowerForChannel is -30 to -43(detected the voice) then if it the PeakPowerChannel is -160 or less it will Play the recorded file... Now, my problem is that when I Record for more than 5t imes, my I wasn't able to hear now my Recorded File, I dont know  what is the problem.. please help.. im totally noob...

Comment: need help badly.. please

Comment: up.. need answers please... T_T